# Format incosistency with ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy.ndarray in which i substitute all the values with some 6 digits precision floats. At the time that i make the assignment i do sth like this:

```
data[i][j]=format(value,'6.f')
```

`data[i][j]` if i print it now with `print data[i][j]` it has this format `234.434567.`

When the loop finished and i do `print data` now `data[i][j]` has this format `2.34434567e+something` for all the values

How can i make the ndarray to have the format i want when i print it?

Comment: On a side note, if you're dealing with numpy arrays, there's no need to use `data[i][j]`. Use `data[i,j]` instead.  Also, you're trying to assign a _string_ as an item in a floating point array. It's being cast to a float behind the scenes, but you really should avoid doing that.

Comment: @JoeKington explain me then how i should do the assignment and why i should avoid it

Comment: If you're working with a float, then just assign it (don't convert it to a string by using `format`).  If you're working with a string, then explicitly cast it to a float. Right now, you're taking a floating point value and changing it to a string (losing precision) and then changing it back to a float.  What it looks like you wanted to do is just `data[i,j] = value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array(
    [
        [1.23456789, 2.34567890],
        [0.00000001, 0.22222222]
    ]
)


print data

--output:--
[[  1.23456789e+00   2.34567890e+00]
 [  1.00000000e-08   2.22222220e-01]]



np.set_printoptions(
    precision=6,
    suppress=True,  #get rid of scientific notation(e.g. e+00)
)

print data

--output:--
[[ 1.234568  2.345679]
 [ 0.        0.222222]]
```

Comment: +1 (You beat me to it!) It might also be good to add a link to the `set_printoptions` documentation: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html

Comment: Is there a similar option that would specify how many precision digits to take into account when manipulation between ndarrays need to be done?

Comment: @curious - You seem to be confused with the difference between strings and floats (based on the code in your question, anyway).  Numpy arrays are floats, ints, etc.  If it's a floating point array, it will use floating point math. If it's an integer array, it will use integer math.  For floating point (and integer) arrays, there are different bit-depths (e.g. 32-bit, 64-bit, etc). These control the precision of the result, but floating point math does not have a direct relationship to "precision digits". This is true in any programming language.